# How to test for Exception thrown for a method using StepVerfier

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spock

I created a simple service to save a list of products in a list. I want to test the case that passing an empty list to the service should throw an exception. However the test fails with a NullPointerException at the StepVerifier.create(...).  Here is the skeleton of the service.

```java
                       public class ProductService {
                         
                         private final ProductRepository productRepository;

                         public Flux<Product> saveAll(List<Product> products) {
                           if(ObjectUtils.isEmpty(products)){
                          
                           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot save null or empty 
                            list of products!");
                          }
                          return productRepository.saveAll(products);
                        }
                      }
```

Here is the test method:

```java
       def "Empty product list should throw an exception when saving products"() {
            given:

            def products = []

            productRepository.saveAll(products) >>{ throw new IllegalArgumentException()}                                                                          
                                                                                                
            when:
            def result = productService.saveAlll(products)

            then:

            StepVerifier.create(result) .expectError(IllegalArgumentException)
           }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `StepVerifier.create()` accepts `Publisher` type to subscribe and verify. However, you are throwing just `IllegalArgumentException` which is not `Publisher`. Instead you should return `Flux` that terminates with error.

```java
public Flux<Product> saveAll(List<Product> products) {
  if(ObjectUtils.isEmpty(products)){
    return Flux.error(new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot save null or empty list of products!"));
  }
  return productRepository.saveAll(products);
}
```

then in it can be verified:

```java
def result = productService.saveAlll(Collections.empyList());
StepVerifier.create(result)
        .expectError(IllegalArgumentException.class)
        .verify();
```